# pandas: merge help two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a Question in Pandas

two dataframe I want merge.

example)

First DataFrame is here

```
Year Month Location
 2006  01    NY
 2006  01    CA
 2006  02    CA
 2006  02    NY
```

and Second DataFrame is here

```
Type
A
B
C
```

how can I merge it?

I wanna like this

```
   Year Month Location Type
   2006  01    NY       A
   2006  01    NY       B
   2006  01    NY       C
   2006  01    CA       A
   2006  01    CA       B
   2006  01    CA       C
```

Thanks, for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) by new columns `tmp` if need cartesian product. Last [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) column `tmp`:

```
df1['tmp'] = 1
df2['tmp'] = 1
df = pd.merge(df1,df2, on='tmp').drop('tmp', axis=1)
print (df)
    Year  Month Location Type
0   2006      1       NY    A
1   2006      1       NY    B
2   2006      1       NY    C
3   2006      1       CA    A
4   2006      1       CA    B
5   2006      1       CA    C
6   2006      2       CA    A
7   2006      2       CA    B
8   2006      2       CA    C
9   2006      2       NY    A
10  2006      2       NY    B
11  2006      2       NY    C
```