# Pandas df. Match values of a column from one dataframe with a values from a column from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

There it seems to be some similar questions and solutions but I really can't apply properly any of them to my problem.

The problem is the following:

I have one `df` called `views`

```
s_id   cookie   product_id  brand
11      1221      1           0
22      12312     1           0
33      231       2           1
44      23123     3           2
```

The other is `purchases`

```
s_id   cookie   product_id   price
11      1221      1           100
22      12312     1           100
33      231       2           200
44      23123     3           300
```

Session `id` and `cookie` play no role here, I'll use them later for other purposes, what I need is basically map `product_id` in `purchases` with `brand` from `views`, i.e. I want to have `purchases` dataframe to look like this:

```
s_id   cookie   product_id   price   brand
11      1221      1           100    0
22      12312     1           100    0
33      231       2           200    1
44      23123     3           300    2
```

Help me please! Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas: merge help two dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40815775/pandas-merge-help-two-dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like `pd.merge`

```
dfC = pd.merge(dfA, dfB)
```

Output

```
s_id    cookie  product_id  brand   price
0   11  1221    1               0   100
1   22  12312   1               0   100
2   33  231     2               1   200
3   44  23123   3               2   300
```